# Why do YouTube videos become greyish in Chrome if hardware acceleration is disabled?

Tags: youtube

**Update: One of the tests has shown that the problem persists on certain devices even if the hardware acceleration is enabled.** The 4 screenshots below were taken on Windows 10, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m (64-bit), nVidia GeForce GT240M.

[image: YouTube screenshots compared with/without Hardware Acceleration in Chrome]

[image: YouTube screenshots compared with/without Hardware Acceleration in Chrome]

I've just made some tests, see the results below.

**White as expected:**

- Windows 10, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m (64-bit), nVidia GeForce GT240M, HACC ON.
- Windows 10, Firefox, nVidia GeForce GT240M, HACC ON.
- Windows 10, Firefox, nVidia GeForce GT240M, HACC OFF.
- Windows 10, Edge, nVidia GeForce GT240M, HACC ?.
- Windows 10, IE11, nVidia GeForce GT240M, HACC ?.
- Windows 10, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m (64-bit), nVidia GeForce GT630M, HACC ON.
- Windows  7, Firefox, SyS Mirage 3 Graphics, HACC ON.
- Windows  7, Firefox, SyS Mirage 3 Graphics, HACC OFF.
- Android 5.0.1, Chrome, Adreno 320, HACC ?.
- Android 5.0.1, YouTube, Adreno 320, HACC ?.

**Grey bug:**

- Windows 10, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m (64-bit), nVidia GeForce GT240M, HACC OFF.
- Windows 10, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m (64-bit), nVidia GeForce GT630M, HACC OFF.
- Windows  7, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m, SyS Mirage 3 Graphics, **HACC ON**.
- Windows  7, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m, SyS Mirage 3 Graphics, HACC OFF.

Comment: Can you share a comparison of a regular video-frame and is your player Flash or HTML5?

Comment: What do you mean by a regular video-frame? The picture I've posted contains 2 screenshots of the same video-frame: with hardware acceleration disabled on the left, and with hardware acceleration enabled on the right. Both screenshots have been taken in Google Chrome while watching the same video. The player is HTML5.

Comment: As in some live action, not flat color. Offhand, it looks like a gamma correction error.

Comment: I'll take a screenshot soon of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEKEjpTzB0Q).

Comment: @Mulvya I've added new screenshots, hope this helps.

Comment: Seems related to this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=576482